# How to add accuracy check to a calculation using the trapezoidal method

Tags: c, math, calculation, floating-accuracy

I managed to make a calculation, but I do not understand how to check the accuracy:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    double a, b, h, s, x;
    int i, n;
    printf("Enter a, b, n: ");
    scanf("%lf %lf %d", &a, &b, &n);
    h = (b - a) / n;
    x = a;
    s = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        x = x + h;
        s = s + pow(x, 3) * exp(2 * x);
    }
    s = h * (pow(a, 3) * exp(2 * a) + pow(b, 3) * exp(2 * b) + 2 * s) / 2;
    printf("Integral = %lf\n", s);
}
```

Comment: what is being calculated here, using what algorithm

Comment: One check is to compare the final value of `x` with `b` — the two could be different because of rounding effects when you calculated `h`.  Kernighan & Plauger say, in their old but classic book "The Elements of
Programming Style", that:

* _A wise old programmer once said "floating-point numbers are like
  little piles of sand; every time you move one, you lose a little sand
  and gain a little dirt"._

They also say:

* _10 * 0.1 is hardly ever 1.0_

Both sayings point out that floating-point arithmetic is not precise.

Comment: @pm100: The code uses the [trapezoid rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) to approximate the area under the curve x^3•e^2x from x=a to x=b using n trapezoids.

Comment: Error analysis is discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Error_analysis).